# Describe |00> and |10> in terms of |0> and |1>

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I came across following lines:

$|00\rangle$ : both quibts are in state of $|0\rangle$

since $|00\rangle = [1 0 0 0]$ in column vector and $|0\rangle = [1 0]$ in column vector, so if each single qubit is $[1 0]$ then how multi-qubit state $|00\rangle = [1 0 0 0]$ ?

Is it like each single qubit have 100% probability of being in first state basis so in multi-qubit system they have 100% probability of being in first state basis?

---

$|10\rangle$ : The qubit states are $|1\rangle$ (on the left) and $|0\rangle$  (on the right).

since $|10\rangle = [0 0 1 0]$

$|0\rangle = [1 0]$

$|1\rangle = [0 1]$

so if one qubit is in $|0\rangle$ and other in $|1\rangle$ then how in multi-qubit system $|10\rangle = [0 0 1 0]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector of a non-entangled multiple-qubits state is given by the tensor product of the one-qubits vectors :
$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a*c\\a*d\\b*c\\b*d\end{pmatrix}$$
thus :
$$|00\rangle = |0\rangle \otimes|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
and :
$$|10\rangle = |1\rangle \otimes|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
In a two qubits state $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\ \beta\\ \gamma\\ \delta\end{pmatrix}$:

- the probability of observing $|00\rangle$ is $|\alpha|²$
- the probability of observing $|01\rangle$ is $|\beta|²$
- the probability of observing $|10\rangle$ is $|\gamma|²$
- the probability of observing $|11\rangle$ is $|\delta|²$